# Why dict.pop() in loop removes key from dict created in future loop iteration?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 0.1, 'c': 'yes'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 'no'}]
```

When I loop through the list, I can obviously print the value of the key "c". There is no problem if I remove this key with `pop()` after printing, because the dictionary `my_dict` (as far as I understand) is re-created in every iteration of the loop.

```
for my_dict in list_dicts:
    print my_dict['c']
    my_c = my_dict.pop('c', 'dunno')
```

However, when I re-run the code above inside another loop:

```
for i in xrange(1,3):
    for my_dict in list_dicts:
        print my_dict['c']
        my_c = my_dict.pop('c', 'dunno')
```

then I get the error `KeyError: 'c'` in the `print my_dict['c']` of the second iteration of the outer loop (`i=2`).

I don't understand why that happens. The error disappears if I re-create the `list_dicts` after the first loop:

```
for i in xrange(1,3):
    for my_dict in list_dicts:
        print my_dict['c']
        my_c = my_dict.pop('c', 'dunno')
    list_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 0.1, 'c': 'yes'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 'no'}]
```

but I don't understand why `list_dicts` has been modified.

Could somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: Your assumption that it gets recreated every iteration is not true

Answer (score 4):

`my_dict` is a reference to the dict in `list_dicts`. It's *not* a copy of the dict, it's a direct reference to it. Modifying `my_dict` modifies the elements of `list_dicts`.

You can verify this by printing `list_dicts` after the pop.

```
for my_dict in list_dicts:
    print my_dict['c']
    my_c = my_dict.pop('c', 'dunno')
    print list_dicts
```

If you want copies of the dicts you need to explicitly create them.

```
for my_dict in list_dicts:
    copy = dict(my_dict)
    my_c = copy.pop('c', 'dunno')
```